Specify expiration time when requesting access token in microsoft login oauth2 v2.0
I am generating a JWT token by making a post to this URL to log in to Microsoft:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TENANT_ID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
I am doing some integration tests and I want to test the authentication of my API, for this I need to generate a token that lasts very little time, something like 5 minutes or less, and the defaults last 1 hour.
I have not found information about this in the documentation.
I hope to be able to set an exact expiration time.

Refer this documentation and this SO thread let me know is this works for you or not

Is this solution works for you?

yes, yes! sorry I was busy with other things but now I was able to check your answers and yes, they are just what I needed, thank you very much.

The minimum duration  of Access Token Lifetime is 10minutes.
To configure  accessTokenLifetimePolicy  , you should have atleast Microsoft Entra ID P1 license.
Initially, I registered Microsoft Entra ID application, gave necessary API permission and granted admin consent like below:

Now, generated access token using client credential flow using below code snippet:
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token 
client_id=<app_id>
client_secret = <client_secret>
grant_type = client_credentials
scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/.default



After generating access token, I tried to configure AccesstokenLifeTimePolicy for 5 minutes using below code snippet but get error like below:
Authorization : Bearer token
Body : raw

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies

{

"definition": [

"{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"00:05:00\"}}"

],

"displayName": "New token lifetime policy for application",

"isOrganizationDefault": false

}


Using same access token, I successfully configured AccesstokenLifeTimePolicy for 10 minutes using below code snippet  :
Authorization : Bearer token
Body : raw

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies

{

"definition": [

"{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"00:10:00\"}}"

],

"displayName": "New token lifetime policy",

"isOrganizationDefault": false

}


Now, assigning  tokenLifetimePolicies  to application using below parameters:
Authorization : Bearer Token
Body: raw

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<ServicePrincipalID/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref

{

"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/<policy-id>"

}




So, when I generated the access token with resource API scope of assigned application, it will give the access token having 10 minutes lifetime successfully as below:


Reference:
Minimum duration token lifetimes
Assigning token lifetime policy to app registration Microsoft Graph. - Microsoft Q&A by  Fabio Andrade
Set lifetimes for tokens - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Learn

@alergio Glad it works for you!
